# Parse.com Sencha Touch 2.0

Tags: parsing, extjs, sencha-touch-2

Wondering if connecting Sencha Touch 2.0 with parse.com framework even possible. I have been trying for a day or so and can't figure it out. Please let me know if it is, I know it was possible with Sencha Touch 1.0 but not sure about 2.0

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible to use Parse with Sencha Touch.

The [Parse REST API](https://parse.com/docs/rest) means that you can use any front end code "web app" like Sencha, jQuery Mobile, JavaScript, PHP ... etc. by using using the developer keys provided by them when you create an account and register an app on their dashboard.

You can do a lot more than just storing and retrieving data as well.

For instance you can get your users to sign up or log in to an app you've created using Facebook or Twitter.

[Link to Facebook and Twitter Now Available Through the REST API](http://blog.parse.com/2012/03/01/link-to-facebook-and-twitter-now-available-through-the-rest-api/)

Have a look at the examples in the Parse REST API to get your head around doing calls to the service.

Please don't hesitate to ask for more clarification if this is confusing.

:)

Answer (score 0):

There used to be an issue with the CORS headers that the Scenica touch required for the REST APIs. This has been resolved. Your code should work now.

Answer (score 0):

There is a third party library specifically for accessing Parse with Sencha Touch.

See https://github.com/blounty/Sencha-Touch-Parse-Client

via https://parse.com/docs/api_libraries

Answer (score -1):

I'm using the Parse REST API together with ST2.1, but I'm facing some problems.

See my post on Sencha forum:

http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?256679-Problem-with-preflight-requests-in-a-model-store-connected-to-parse.com&p=939514#post939514

The use of preflight requests is causing me a weird problem in Safari iOS6/6.1. The network activity indicator in the status bar keeps loading..

Don't know if it's something in Sencha or a bug in Safari, because it's working fine in Chrome.